# Use network reputation rather than site reputation for reminding users to accept answers

Tags: feature-request, reputation

Users with insufficient reputation on an SE site are reminded that they can accept an answer when they upvote an answer to their question. I believe this should be based on "cross-network" reputation (as reputation is displayed in chat) rather than the site reputation. Yes, my reputation on SO is a mere 250, but my 6172 reputation on MSE should suggest that I have a clue how the SE model works.